# running a simple script on directory

Tags: python

I made a simple program to test this out. It simply finds any instance of a specific string, and replaces it with a new string.  What I want to do is run this against my entire directory, file by file.

```
def replace(directory, oldData, newData):
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        f = open(file,'r')
        filedata = f.read()
        newdata = filedata.replace(oldData,newData)
        f = open(file, 'w')
        f.write(newdata)
        f.close()
```

But I keep getting an error message telling me that one of files doesnt exist in my directory, even though it does. I can't figure out why it would tell me that.

Comment: `os.listdir` just returns the filenames, they don't have the directory prefix. Use `os.path.join` to connect them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir()` returns a list of strings much like the terminal command `ls`.  It lists the names of the files, but it does not include the name of the directory.  You need to add that yourself with `os.path.join()`:

```
def replace(directory, oldData, newData):
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        file = os.path.join(directory, file)
        f = open(file,'r')
        filedata = f.read()
        newdata = filedata.replace(oldData,newData)
        f = open(file, 'w')
        f.write(newdata)
        f.close()
```

I would not recommend `file` as a variable name, however, because it conflicts with the built-in type.  Also, it is recommended to use a `with` block when dealing with files.  The following is my version:

```
def replace(directory, oldData, newData):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        filename = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        with open(filename) as open_file:
            filedata = open_file.read()
            newfiledata = filedata.replace(oldData, newData)
            with open(filename, 'w') as write_file:
                f.write(newfiledata)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way :

```
def replace(directory, oldData, newData):
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        f = open(os.path.join(directory, file),'r')
        filedata = f.read()
        newdata = filedata.replace(oldData,newData)
        f = open(os.path.join(directory, file), 'w')
        f.write(newdata)
        f.close()
```